# Eclipse CDT - Link individual library with space in file path

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, eclipse-cdt

Using Eclipse CDT, I am trying to link a single library (.lib) file into my project.

[image: Eclipse setup]

During compilation, as a result of the space character in the file path, the path is split around the space, causing the file to not be found, and preventing compilation from executing successfully.  This execution string is generated by Eclipse.

```
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o "Test.exe" "src\\Test.o" -lC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/jvm.lib 
g++: error: Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/jvm.lib: No such file or directory
```

Overall, it has trouble constructing the library option for compilation:

```
-lC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/jvm.lib
```

I've tried both surrounding the path in quotes and adding the path's directory as a library path, yet the `-l` option is malformed in both cases.

**How can I successfully add a library with a space in its path into Eclipse CDT?**

Comment: What happens, if you enclose path with quotes in GUI?

Comment: @Lol4t0 It forms the option to enclose the `-l` within quotes along with the file path, which isn't a valid option formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should enclose your path, that has spaces, with qoutes.
2. You probably should specify only library name (that is `jvm`) at the *Libraries tab*. Then specify `"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib"` at the *Library Paths* tab.

The point is that `"-lC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/jvm.lib"` *is* valid option formation, as command interpreter will treat it as a single option but drop quotations.

So, when you type `g++ "-lC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/jvm.lib"` in cmd, argument passed to g++ will be `-lC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/jvm.lib` without quotes.

However, `-l<path-to-library-file>` is invalid option for `gcc` itself. You can either use
`g++ <path-to-library-file>` or `g++ -L<path-to-library-dir> -l<library-name>`.

So, valid options would be

```
g++ <..> "src\\Test.o" "-LC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib" -ljvm
```

Comment: With those exact options, the `jvm` library isn't linked (the error message being related to its referenced code).  I also tried passing `-ljvm.lib`, but that results in an error as well: `cannot find -ljvm.lib`.

Comment: @Vulcan, if it does not blame that `cannot find <lib>`, then it _is_ linked. But may be library does not contains symbols you need, or may be it uses different ABI. You can study symbols table with `objdump -t <path-to-lib>`

Comment: Interesting; Eclipse recognizes the symbol reference and shows no error in the source, so the necessary symbols are definitely there.  However, upon running `objdump` on `jvm.dll`, I get countless errors of "File format not recognized" and "Recognized but unhandled machine type".  Looks like it uses a different ABI then?

Comment: Turns out that g++ only supports the 32-bit `jvm.lib`, so I've changed the file path to link that library instead. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Vulcan Otherwise, you could use 64bit-targeted mingw, if you have 64-bit versions of all your libraries. You can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/)